# Is there any easy way to open/close bay window blinds at the same time?

Tags: blinds

We have a bay window with normal wooden venetian blinds. The bay window has 5 individual blinds like this (http://www.mainfineintl.com/documents/FauxWood1.jpg) which use a twisting rod to open and close them.

Is there any simple way to link the rods together so only one has to be turned to rotate all of them? I'd like to be able to control all with one synchronously - we normally have them all open or closed at the same time so independent controls isn't needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible yes.  Simple, not so much.

Comment: You just need a 5-handed-grabber for this.

Comment: @ mike: by simple I am hoping for a solution I can make at home. But thinking about it, it seems quite complex. I can't think of any easy way myself...

Answer (score 1):

We have the exact same situation (bay window with 5 panes and 5 independent blinds) and I have toyed with the idea of mechanically ganging them all together.

The point where the twisting rod enters turns a cam which is coupled to a pulley system to tilt the slats.   I posit that an appropriate line wrapped around each "twister" could do all of them at once.

I have not attempted it though—not even had a look inside.  The set of blinds cost over $800 and my wife is quite reluctant for me to perform experiments which could affect the appearance or function.  And she doesn't mind one bit if it takes me 30+ extra seconds per day twisting each individually.